# Convert XY (SRID 4326) to UTM in spatialite returns NULL

Tags: coordinate-system, spatialite, utm

How can I convert EPSG4326 point to UTM in spatialite?

```
SRID=4326;POINT(51.2506238 35.70442974)
```

Executing `X(TRANSFORM(Geometry, 32639)) as X`  always returns NULL. What's the proper way of extracting northing and easting from geometry type 4326?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've not given a reproducible example, but here's one:

```
spatialite> select X(transform(GeomFromText("POINT (0 0)",27700),4326));
X(transform(GeomFromText("POINT (0 0)",27700),4326))
-7.55715980520632
```

The X coordinate of (0,0) in epsg:27700 is -7.55 degrees in epsg:4326.

And here it is in `spatialite-gui` (version 2.0.0):

[image]

if this fails for you, then there's something wrong or just different with your Spatialite installation.

I'm not sure what your `"SRID=..."` line is suppose to be. Is that some text in a geometry column? I've constructed a geometry from a string in WKT format with the SRID passed to the `GeomFromText` function.

Comment: "SRID=..." is just represention of my geometry point type. I mean how can I extract easting and northing from existing field

Comment: Is it a valid representation of a point in Spatialite SQL? How are you converting this to a geometry type?

Comment: this is what spatialite-gui show about the geometry field

SRID: 4326

Geometry type: POINT

#1 POINT:
  1) 51.2506  35.7044

Comment: executing select X(transform(GeomFromText("POINT (0 0)",27700),4326)); in spatialite-gui 2.0.0-devel returns null also

Comment: @user30184 good point, but double quotes seems to work for me also. hmmm...

Comment: it seems like there is a problem with spatialite-gui in windows. the transform function does not works at all. is there any extension need to be loaded?

Comment: I suggest to edit your answer and use syntax that works both with SpatiaLite and PostGIS `select ST_X(ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('POINT (0 0)',27700),4326));`. Enclosing WKT between double quotes is definitely wrong SQL even SpatiaLite indeed seems to accept it. The meaning in standard SQL is "field names as "POINT (0 0)"".

Comment: Works for me with Spatialite-gui 2.0.0devel on Windows. Do you have the corresponging rows for EPSG:4326 and EPSG:27700 in the spatial_ref_sys table of your SpatiaLite database?

Comment: the spatialite-gui throws an error: SQL error: no such table spatial_ref_sys

Comment: Then you can't reproject your data. But spatialite database should always have that table and at least on row in it. How have you created your database?

Comment: i used https://github.com/sevar83/android-spatialite to develop a native app upon android. yes it seams like there is not such table in metadata

Comment: If you start from nothing you'll have quite a bit of learning. Start from this http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-latest.html and all SpatiaLite tutorials you can find and which deal with at least version 4.0. What you especially seem not miss is function init_spatial_metadata, possibly with mode "none" with a couple of subsequent InsertEpsgSrid for keeping the database small as you probably want for Android devices.

Comment: @user30184 your help is appreciated.